# Android - Filtering html tags from XML(Rss/Atom) Feed using Regular Expressions

Tags: java, android, html, xml, regex

I am developing a newsreader app for my website http:**//www.werchelsea.com/** that gets the latest news from the feed: http://www.werchelsea.com/feed/atom/ and I am succesful to get the feed properly and casting it into a string. Now my main problem is that my feed description contains data with html tags like:

```
<p>It was Raul Meireles who came from the Merseyside to London to complete his move from Liverpool to Chelsea on the dead line day of the summer transfer window last year, when Chelsea failed to sign the highly-rated midfielder, Luka Modric. Chelsea were left with no other choice but to sign the Portuguese midfielder.</p>
<p>Meireles was a regular starter under the management of Villas-Boas, he really enjoyed working under

<a href='http://www.werchelsea.com/2012/09/05/time-to-say-good-bye-to-raul-meireles/303777_153113331443746_1122718871_n/' title='303777_153113331443746_1122718871_n'><img width="150" height="150" src="http://www.werchelsea.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/303777_153113331443746_1122718871_n-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail" alt="Meireles first training session with Chelsea football club" title="303777_153113331443746_1122718871_n" /></a>
```

What I tried was replacing all these tags with regular expression but for some reason I am not able to find a correct RE to match all the html tag types. What I used to replace was:

```
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

    String response="";
    try{
     URL feedwebsite=new URL(feedURL);
     SAXParserFactory spf=SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
     SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
     XMLHandler feedHandler=new XMLHandler();
     XMLReader feedReader=sp.getXMLReader();
     feedReader.setContentHandler(feedHandler);
     InputSource is=new InputSource(feedwebsite.openStream());
     feedReader.parse(is);
     response=feedHandler.getParsedFeed().replaceAll("<"+"[0-9a-zA-Z]+"+">","_").replaceAll("</"+"[0-9a-zA-Z]+"+">","-").replaceAll("<"+"[0-9a-zA-Z]+"+"/>",".");  
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        response="Cannot Connect to the server.Please Check your Wifi/Data   Connection.";
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return response;
}***
```

If replacing the string using RE is the correct procedure for this or is there any other way please help me.

Answer (score 0):

To match an HTML tag (opening or closing), use this regex:

```
<[^>]+?>
```

Comment: ya but what about the html tags with attributes? 
thanx!

Comment: The regex above also matches tags with attributes. It looks for an opening angle bracket, then for any character that is not a closing angle bracket (which includes equal, quotes, etc). It will finally stop after the first closing angle bracket. Try it at http://regexpal.com/

Btw, that regex also matches comments. Use this one if you don't want to match them: <[^!>]+>